# Проблема с AVD после обновления SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

Обновил SDK до версии 4.4 KitKat и при попытке запустить приложение в AVD (приложение до обновления загружалось без проблем и никаких изменений в код не вносилось).

Error Log пишет:

```
No command output when running: 'am start -n ru.fun.post/ru.fun.post.ZeroActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5554
com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:430)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:347)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:435)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(ActivityLaunchAction.java:67)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.ActivityLaunchAction.doLaunchAction(ActivityLaunchAction.java:109)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doLaunchAction(AndroidLaunchController.java:1286)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.doLaunchAction(AndroidLaunchController.java:1298)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launchApp(AndroidLaunchController.java:1270)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.simpleLaunch(AndroidLaunchController.java:906)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.continueLaunch(AndroidLaunchController.java:748)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.AndroidLaunchController.launch(AndroidLaunchController.java:570)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.doLaunch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:322)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:238)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Переустановил Eclipse ADT и  SDK - не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

удали версию 4.4 KitKat... мне помогло

Comment: А Х Р Е Н Е Т Ь !

Comment: Мне то же помогло. 
А проблема то в чём? Ведь не за горами момент, когда понадобиться 4.4.